# Rails mounted engine load paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, path, partial-views, rails-engines

I have the following method which loads a set of partials which lives in a helper:

```
Dir.new(File.join(Rails.root,"app","views", path)).each do |partial|
      concat(render :partial => File.join("/" + path, partial.sub(/^_/, "")))
      if partial.starts_with?('_')
      end
      ""
end
```

When I load my `edit.html.erb` I include the helper as you would expect to load all of my partials:

```
<% render_all_in_path "shared/setting_editors" -%>
```

When I mount my Engine, I'm able to extend my controllers as you would expect, but my helper method does not seem to work when I include my `_partial.html.erb` within the engines `views/shared/setting_editors` folder.

How could I improve the above helper method so that `_partial.html.erb` files I include in the mounted engine are loaded in my Rails application?

Comment: That is some weird code. You render and join all partials from a directory? Why not have a partial that renders them in order?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dir.glob( File.join( Rails.root, "app", "views", "**", "_*" ) ).each do |partial|
  # this will iterate over all the partials in the app/views/ subdirectories
end
```